# Extract modified and added lines from two csv files using shell or diff command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, diff

I have two csv files F1 and F2 having rows in same order, I want to extract changed/added lines by comparing files F1 and F2 from F2.

I tried diff command but i could see the change. How could i read the pattern and extract the lines from F2?

F1(File 1):

```
1234,Joe,pieter,joe@gmail.com,male,22
1235,Shally,Jonse,shally@yahoo.com,female,24
1235,Harry,poter,harry@gmail.com,male,21
1235,Helen,Jairag,helen@gmail.com,female,21
2585,Dinesh,Jairag,helen@gmail.com,female,21
```

F2(File 2):

```
1234,Joe,pieter,joe@gmail.com,male,22
1235,Shally,Jonse,shally@yahoo.com,female,24
1235,Harry,Potter,harry@gmail.com,male,21
1235,Helen,Jairag,helen@gmail.com,female,21
```

Command executed:

```
diff F2 F1
```

Out put:

```
3c3
< 1235,Harry,Potter,harry@gmail.com,male,21
---
> 1235,Harry,poter,harry@gmail.com,male,21
4a5
> 2585,Dinesh,Jairag,helen@gmail.com,female,21
```

Expected Output in a file F3:

```
1235,Harry,poter,harry@gmail.com,male,21
2585,Dinesh,Jairag,helen@gmail.com,female,21
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, can you add the expected output?

Comment: Thanks i have added a expected output,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped to extract lines and write in a new file

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to extract changed/added lines **from File2**!
So in your example there is just one changed line in File2 and no added line in File2.
The basic call pattern for `diff` is `diff old new` and the output tells you what need to be done to update `old`. So to learn what is different in File2 you would use it as second argument. I would suggest to use `-u` option to `diff`. This gives you every line from File2 that need be changed/added in File1 with a 
`+` in the first pos.:

```
diff -u File1 File2
```

gives

```
--- File1   2012-08-22 11:30:07.000000000 +0200
+++ File2   2012-08-22 11:30:25.000000000 +0200
@@ -1,5 +1,4 @@
 1234,Joe,pieter,joe@gmail.com,male,22
 1235,Shally,Jonse,shally@yahoo.com,female,24
-1235,Harry,poter,harry@gmail.com,male,21
+1235,Harry,Potter,harry@gmail.com,male,21
 1235,Helen,Jairag,helen@gmail.com,female,21
-2585,Dinesh,Jairag,helen@gmail.com,female,21
```

Now filter only the lines that start with `+` except the first two:

```
diff -u data1 data2 | \
  awk 'NR > 2 && $0 ~ /^+/ {print substr($0,2)}'

1235,Harry,Potter,harry@gmail.com,male,21
```

Or the other way round:

```
diff -u data2 data1 | \
  awk 'NR > 2 && $0 ~ /^+/ {print substr($0,2)}'

1235,Harry,poter,harry@gmail.com,male,21
2585,Dinesh,Jairag,helen@gmail.com,female,21
```